# Laravel - Counting from third relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

I have the following code:

```
        $main = Main::with(['clients', 'events.orderitems' => function($query) {
        $query->whereIn('order_id', function($query) {
            $query->select('id')->from('orders')->where('orderPaid', 1)->orWhere('orderStatus', 3);
        });
    }])->where('id', $id)->first();

    foreach($main->events as $dates) {
        $all_paid = 0;
        $all_pending = 0;
        foreach($dates->orderitems as $item) {
            if($item->orderPaid == 1) {
                $all_paid = $all_paid + $item->quantity;
            }

        }
        $dates->orderscount = $all_paid;

        foreach($dates->orderitems as $item) {
            if($item->orderStatus == 3) {
                $all_pending = $all_pending + $item->quantity;
            }

        }
        $dates->pendingcount = $all_pending;

    }
```

Is there maybe an MYSQL way to Count the PAID orders and the orders with orderStatus == 3 in the SQL? I think, how I am doing it, it's way to messy and not very good for the performance.

So a "Main" has n-events which have n-orderItems.

I need to get to a "Main" Event, all the Events with all PAID and orderStatus == 3 items. How can I do that?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION:**

```
        foreach($main->events as $dates) {
        $dates->orderscount = OrderItems::where('events_id',$dates->id)->whereHas('orders', function($q) {
                $q->where('orderPaid', 1);
            })->sum('quantity');
        $dates->pendingcount = OrderItems::where('events_id',$dates->id)->whereHas('orders', function($q) {
                $q->where('orderStatus', 3);
            })->sum('quantity');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has an [aggregate method](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates) which does just that.

The same way you are using `first` to only get the first result of a query as in:

```
)->where('id', $id)->first();
```

to get the count you could use `count()`

```
 DB::table('orders')->where('orderPaid', 1)->orWhere('orderStatus', 3)->count();
```

If you need the `sum()` of the products and not the `count` as in your title, you could for your particular example use:

```
  $total_quantity = DB::table('orders')->where('orderPaid', 1)->orWhere('orderStatus', 3)->sum('quantity');
```

---

### UPDATE:

As in your example to get both counts you would change you `foreach` to be something similar to:

```
foreach($main->events as $dates) {
    $all_paid = DB::table('orders')->where('order_id',$dates->id)->where('orderPaid', 1)->count();
    $all_pending = DB::table('orders')->where('order_id',$dates->id)->where('orderStatus', 3)->count();

    $dates->orderscount = $all_paid;
    $dates->pendingcount = $all_pending;

}
```

Comment: yes, but I need the both columns separated. Where do I add this statement?

Comment: I updated the answer, but keep in mind this is untested code although it should work

Comment: unfortunately not. Got an error in the foreach because $query isn't defined.

Comment: replace `$query->from()` in both statements to `DB::table('orders')` as in updated answer, untested code leads to this ;) Also I cannot be sure if $dates->id is returned since that part of your code is missing

Comment: nope, sorry... this isn't working. Doesn't find the order_id in order which is obvious because order has the primary "id" and not order_id. It has to do with the main query, not the foreach, isn't it?

Comment: As i said you need to get the `event` id for `->where('order_id',$dates->id)` to have a value. That is in the couple few lines before the code posted. Try to use `->where('order_id',123)` where `123` is a hardcoded id of an event you know has payments and see if it returns the proper values. If so then you need to also return the appropriate id for each event for the code to execute as expected in that `where` clause.

Comment: I did it similar, check my solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() with your eloquent query in laravel. Check under the #Aggregates section here:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries